# Which kernel should I install for Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 in a VMware?

Tags: 14.04, server, vmware

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 in a VMware station on my iMAC which is running on an intel core i5.

My question is: Which kernel should I install, given these options:

1) linux-signed-generic-lts-utopic

2) linux-generic-lts-utopic

3) linux-virtual-lts-utopic

4) linux-signed-image-generic-lts-utopic

5) linux-image-extra-3.16.0-30-generic

6) linux-image-generic-lts-utopic

7) linux-image-virtual-lts-utopic

8) linux-signed-image-3.16.0-30-generic

9) linux-image-3.16.0-30-generic

Comment: Note that the initial boot screen allows you to select a virtual server which will default to the right kernel.  Doing this, will save you a _lot_ of effort.

Comment: Why not go with the default?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you might want to choose number two. If guessing that you're installing ubuntu 14.10 instead of 14.04 right? but I'm not sure why utopic is LTS.

Comment: I just double checked the Ubuntu website and the download package is Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 LTS.  But yeah I picked number 2 like you said.

Comment: @grepmaster just fyi Utopic is not LTS but 14.04.2 uses Utopic's default kernel that's why lots of people get confused I guess. :)